# Laravel Routes Based On MySQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, url-routing

I'm trying to build a catalog of movies that I own and I would like to set up a route like so

```
Route::get('movie/{name}', array('uses' => 'MovieController@showMovie'));
```

With a controller of

```
class MovieController extends BaseController 
{
public function showMovie($name)
{
    $movie = Movie::firstByAtrributes(array('name' => $name));

    return View::make('movie', array( 'movie' => $movie));
    }
}
```

However, I want the name to be pulled from the database, for instance if I have a table called Movies, within the table I have, ID, title and cover_art.

When I type myurl.com/movie/findingnemo it will display the relevant information about that movie for me without having to create a movietitle.blade.php for every movie that I own.

I can probably figure out the view, it's just the routing I'm struggling with

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with this setup ?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to the following, it should work so that myurl.com/movie/{movieID} will pull up the movie you want.  This seems to make more sense to me, as titles often have spaces and things that would make it a pain to put into the URL.

So you're looking at:

```
class MovieController extends BaseController{
    public function showMovie(Movie $movie){
        return View::make('movie', compact('movie'));
    }
}
```

Then in your view, the movie will be able to be called by $movie->title or whatever for each Movie id.

You'll also have to define the model in route.php

```
Route::model('movie','Movie');
```

And change Route::get('movie/{name}' to Route::get('movie/{movie}'

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use model route binding http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding

```
class MovieController extends BaseController 
{
    public function showMovie(Movie $name)
    {
         return View::make('movie', array( 'movie' => $movie));
    }
}
```

and in the routes files

```
Route::model('movie', 'Movie');
```

then add the closure to select movie by slug

```
Route::bind('movie', function($value, $route)
{
    return $movie = Movie::firstByAtrributes(array('name' => $value));
});
```

also you have to update your route redirecto to the contoller to

```
Route::get('movie/{movie}', array('uses' => 'MovieController@showMovie'));
```